# Google Datastore vs CloudSQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql

I am working on standing up a mobile app with Google Datastore as backend database. I am debating whether google datastore is right choice for below use cases vs other datastorage options google offers. We are a small team and we don't want to incur lot of operations costs in the initial run. Application will have the following use cases:

1. User registration and profile which will take user personal identification details like credit cards, bank account , emails,address etc
2. Various subscription plans like yearly subscription price, monthly subscription price and pay per single service . User will be charged with bank account or credit card set on user profile
3. Mobile app will be launched within next 2 months and i am expecting at-least 1000 users in first few months

Appreciate your feedback at this stage where we are laying down the foundation of the app

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Datastore is good to manage user profiles and the use cases that you're referring as well it has [free quota amounts and low costs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing#top_of_page) regarding its usage and it'll be a better option compared with Cloud SQL which price and storage capacity is limited to the machine type that you're using. Additionally, as this isn't a technical inquiry, but a solution concern, I suggest posting this on the [Datastore Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/gcd-discuss) where ideas regarding the Datastore and other products would be properly exchanged.